# Mongoose error on aggregate group

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

i have this model:

```
var Chat = new Schema({
    from: String,
    to: String,
    satopId: String,
    createdAt: Date
});
var Chat = mongoose.model('Chat', Chat);
```

I want do a query to do a query that returns the max created at grouping by to and from field. I tried with:

```
Chat.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: '$to',
      from: '$from',
      createdAt: {
        $max: '$createdAt'
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      createdAt: 1,
      from: 1,
      to: 1
    }
  }
], function(err, docs){

})
```

But this generates this error:

> the group aggregate field 'from' must be defined as an expression
>   inside an object

I don't understand what does it mean. How can i solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything "outside" if the `_id` expression in a [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) statement requires a ["grouping operator"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#accumulators) of some sort.

Assuming you are happy with the idea of the "sole" grouping key to be the "to" field in your documents then you probably want something like [**`$first`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/):

```
    Chat.aggregate([
        { "$group": { 
            "_id": "$to", 
            "from": { "$first": "$from" }, 
            "createdAt": { "$max": "$createdAt" } 
        }}, 
        function (err, docs) {
            // do something here
        }
    ])
```

Otherwise if you want "distinct" values on "both" fields then they both belong as a composite value of the grouping key:

```
    Chat.aggregate([
        { "$group": { 
            "_id": {
                "to": "$to", 
                "from": "$from"
            },
            "createdAt": { "$max": "$createdAt" } 
        }}, 
        function (err, docs) {
            // do something here
        }
    ])
```

That's basically how it works. Either it's part of the key or something that needs a grouping operator just like with SQL.

Also note that your [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) assertion is not really required as [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) already does what you are asking there.